# Change password on Vinagre

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, vnc

How does one change the VNC password that vinagre remembers?  It just keeps failing and says "Authentication failed (password check failed)", but never asks for another password.

Answer (score 2):

i just ran into this very issue myself in debian stable.

open a terminal and type `seahorse`.  if you don't have it installed already, run `apt install seahorse`.

in the upper-right corner, type `Remote desktop password` to filter your stored vnc password.  open it by double-clicking, or right-click and choose *Properties*.  click the arrow icon next to Password to change it.  finally, quit seahorse and retry your connection.